# Нужно ли новичку знать и понимать побитовые операции и операции сдвига?

Tags: java, android

Нужно ли новичку знать и понимать побитовые операции и операции сдвига?
Только начинаю изучать Java и в дальнейшем собираюсь изучать Android разработку. Стоит ли сейчас заострять внимание на этих операциях, 2/8/16-чной системах счисления, или Junior/Middle разработчику эти знания вряд ли понадобятся и это уровень Senior и специфичных задач?

Comment: Это уровень самой базы, намного ниже джуна (как для юриста умение читать, например). Другое дело, что применяется оно в Андроиде рядовым разработчиком весьма редко и можно отложить на потом. Впрочем, эти операции очень просты, их полностью за несколько часов разобрать можно. Вообще знать это полезно

Comment: @Alex_Skvortsov а в Java разработке часто применяется, если не брать в расчёт криптографию?

Comment: @fantomrik лично у меня, за 6 лет разработки под Андроид, необходимость в этих операциях возникла лишь единожды)

Comment: На практике даже в андроиде много где использовать можно) 16-ричная система это все что касается цветов в любом программировании (в основе). Побитовые операции в андроиде, например, используются для задания типа клавиатуры при вводе текста. Оба примера - маленькие частные случаи. И да, по бОльшей части такие детали будут от Вас спрятаны. Но знать очень желательно.

Comment: Да найдите какую-нибудь статью с разбором и прочитайте, закройте гештальт.

Comment: @Alex_Skvortsov а можно подробнее, как используются побитовые операции для задания типа клавиатуры при вводе текста? Вы имеете в виду оператор | ? Если да, то боюсь что в данном случае этот оператор выступает как логическое OR. Или я все-таки путаю? Разъясните пожалуйста

Comment: @Circassian [википедия](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Битовая_операция) говорит, что OR - это таки одна из побитовых операций) Моя память подсказывает то же самое)

Comment: @Alex_Skvortsov да, разобрался в вопросе. | - побитовое OR, || - логическое OR :) Оказывается ежедневно работаю с побитовыми операциями и не подозревал об этом) Для меня все они были логическими 

Comment: мое мнение - не фокусироваться на знаниях, в которых нет явной необходимости в ближайшее время, чем быстрее прыгнешь в бассейн, тем быстрее научишься плавать. Теория конечно хорошо, но за 5 секунд барахтания в воде поймешь больше, чем за 5 часов теории

Answer (score 4):

Знать побитовые операции однозначно нужно! 
В этом ответе я постараюсь собрать воедино несколько причин, если что-то забуду - комментируйте.

1. Это самые основы, зная которые Вы будете больше понимать как работает программа.
2. Побитовые сдвиги за место умножения и деления, например, увеличивают скорость программ (хоть и незначительно). Обычно это редко применяется в production, так как уменьшает читаемость кода, но в библиотеках часто так пишут.
3. Чтение кода библиотек. Во многих Core библиотеках используют сдвиги вместо умножения. Например, в скрине ниже Вы можете увидеть как увеличивается размер ArrayList при нехватке места. Таким образом производится умножение на 1.5. [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
4. Побитовые операции часто используются в различных флагах. Например, очень удобно в одном числе совмещать несколько флагов, где каждый бит отвечает за свой флаг. Далее с помощью побитового умножения этот флаг быстро проверяется. Таким образом, увеличиваем скорость работы программы и избегаем лишнего кода.
5. Системы счисления знать необходимо. Как минимум из-за того, что через них задаются цвета (как уже было замечено в комментариях).